# is any way to connect to one datamax printer via usb port with java?

Tags: java, thermal-printer

i was trying to use sdk from datamax that only you can connect via bluethoot or tcp/ip port
but the one that i need to work is via usb port

im trying to do something like this but no luck yet

```html
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

        PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
                flavor, pras);
        PrintService service = findPrintService(printerName, printService);

        DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

        try {

            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);

            job.print(doc, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

well my way to connect was fine with DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE..the only bad that i have was the bytes array that i was sending to printer
need to be according to the DPL Datamax Printer Languague

this is a sample of what you need to send for a text receipt

```html
String STX = new Character((char) 2).toString();
String CR = new Character((char) 0x0d).toString();

String printText = STX
        + "L" + CR
        + "D11" + CR
        + "H14" + CR
        + "121100001200050" + studentname + CR
        + "121100001000050" + studentid + CR
        + "121100000800050" + date + CR
        + "121100000600050" + typeexam + CR
        + "Q0001" + CR
        + "E" + CR;

PrinterService printerService = new PrinterService();
printerService.printBytes("Datamax-O'Neil E-4304 Mark II", printText.getBytes());
```